# why levels of just one variable change after the properly combination of two dataframes?and how should deal it?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, inner-join, right-to-left

I have two dataframes. My first dataframe contains 16 different Lines (genotypes) and due to the different number of plants of each line in my experiment, the str() command shows 145 observation and t 16 levels for my Line variable; as you can see here

```
data.frame':    145 obs. of  15 variables:
 
$ Plate.NO.   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 
$ Line        : Factor w/ 16 levels "L000049","L000154",..: 15 15 15 15 15 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 
$ Strain      : Factor w/ 2 levels "AF1","V31-2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 …

$ Plant.number: int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
$ X0DPI       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 
$ X7DPI       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 
$ X10DPI      : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 ...
$ X12DPI      : num  0.5 0 0 0 2 3 2.5 2.5 2 3 ...
 
$ X14DPI      : num  2.5 1 0 0 2 3 2.5 2.5 2.5 3 ...
 
$ X17DPI      : num  4 1 1 0 3 4 2.5 4 3 3 ...
 
$ X19DPI      : num  4 1 1 1 4 4 2.5 4 3 4 ...
 
$ X21DPI      : num  4 1.5 2 1 4 4 3.5 4 4 4 ...
 
$ X24DPI      : num  4 3 2 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 
$ X26DPI      : num  4 3 2 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 
$ X28DPI      : num  4 3.5 2.5 1.5 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

Also, I have the second dataframe which consists more complementary information for 252 Lines. Here you can see the str() result for my second dataframe

```
data.frame':    252 obs. of  7 variables:
 
$ ID                  : Factor w/ 252 levels "HM001 ","HM002 ",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 
$ Line                : Factor w/ 252 levels "A10","A20","CADL",..: 31 38 175 207 206 169 197  ...
 
$ Population.of.Origin: Factor w/ 252 levels "A10 ","A17_Varma ",..: 157 167 55 53 51 110 ...
 
$ Country.of.Origin   : Factor w/ 19 levels "Algeria ","Cyprus ",..: 16 2 14 1 1 3 3 1 5 8 ...
 
$ Category            : Factor w/ 16 levels "alfalfa ","CC144 ",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 3 ...
 
$ Seeds.From          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Charlie_Brummer,UGA ",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 
$ Status              : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failed.QA","Processed": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 …
```

Out of this 252 Lines I used only 16 Lines for part of my experiment and I want to combine these two dataframes

The first dataframe object is “Rep1” (the one with only 16 Lines) and the second one is called “hap”(the one with 252 Lines)

I used these series of commands

```
inner<-inner_join(Rep1,hap, by = "Line")

left<- left_join(Rep1,hap, "Line")

right←right_join(hap,Rep1,"Line")
```

the combination take place without any problem and I have just the rows for my 16 Lines but surprisingly when the str() output shows me  252 levels for Line instead of 16 while the number of observation is correct
here is the str() output of my datafram after combination

```
'data.frame':   145 obs. of  21 variables:
 
$ ID                  : Factor w/ 252 levels "HM001 ","HM002 ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 
$ Line                : Factor w/ 252 levels "A10","A20","CADL",..: 31 31 31 31 31 31 38 38 38 38 ...
 
$ Population.of.Origin: Factor w/ 252 levels "A10 ","A17_Varma ",..: 157 157 157 157 157 157 167 167 167 167 ...
 
$ Country.of.Origin   : Factor w/ 19 levels "Algeria ","Cyprus ",..: 16 16 16 16 16 16 2 2 2 2 ...
 
$ Category            : Factor w/ 16 levels "alfalfa ","CC144 ",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 
$ Seeds.From          : Factor w/ 6 levels "Charlie_Brummer,UGA ",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 
$ Status              : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failed.QA","Processed": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 
$ Plate.NO.           : int  2 2 2 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 ...
 
$ Strain              : Factor w/ 2 levels "AF1","V31-2": 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 
$ Plant.number        : int  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 ...
 
$ X0DPI               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 
$ X7DPI               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 
$ X10DPI              : num  0 0.5 3 3 2 1 1 0.5 0 0 ...
 
$ X12DPI              : num  0 1.5 3 3 3 3 1 3 0 0 ...
 
$ X14DPI              : num  0.5 3 4 3 3.5 4 2.5 3 1 0 ...
 
$ X17DPI              : num  1 4 4 3 4 4 3 4 1.5 0 ...
 
$ X19DPI              : num  1.5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1.5 0 ...
 
$ X21DPI              : num  2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1.5 0 ...
 
$ X24DPI              : num  2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1.5 1 ...
 
$ X26DPI              : num  3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1.5 1 ...
 
$ X28DPI              : num  3.5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 1 ...
```

Comment: As of dplyr 1.0.0: `Combining multiple factors creates a factor with combined levels; previously it created a character vector with a warning.` See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html. One approach would be to drop the unwanted levels after the join, e.g. `Line = factor(Line)`

Comment: Thank you   @stefan, i will check it